# How can i run "rails routes --expanded" exclusively in Rails6 Test Environment?

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-6

Below details are in reference of Rails 6.

I have created category controller using scaffold in the **test environment**. I want to crosscheck all the routes and its URI using `rails routes --expanded` for test environment.
How can i do that?
As to run that command directly in terminal will give routes of development environment.

I have already checked `rails console -e test` but its exclusively for irb of test env.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RAILS_ENV=environment before the command like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails routes --expanded
```

This will output all routes in your test environment.